# Pause function on element hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image slider that changes images every 5 seconds, but I want the slider to pause when I hover over the div img.  Is there a way to pause the 'theRotator' function on hover and then restart it after the mouse moves out of the div? Thanks all!

```
function theRotator() {
    //Set the opacity of all images to 0
    $('div.rotator ul li').css({opacity: 0.0});

    //Get the first image and display it (gets set to full opacity)
    $('div.rotator ul li:first').css({opacity: 1.0});

    //Call the rotator function to run the slideshow,

    setInterval('rotate()',5000);

}

$(document).ready(function() {      
    //Load the slideshow
    theRotator();
    $('div.rotator').fadeIn(1000);
    $('div.rotator ul li').fadeIn(1000); // tweek for IE
});
```

Comment: For some reason i think you run it twice, why?
I think you should do some think like, run the .delay() -> read about it in jquery.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to clear the timeout on mouseover, and then recreate it on mouseout, like this:

```
var interval;

function theRotator() {
    $('div.rotator ul li').css({opacity: 0.0});
    $('div.rotator ul li:first').css({opacity: 1.0});
    interval = setInterval(rotate, 5000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    theRotator();
    $('div.rotator').fadeIn(1000);
    $('div.rotator ul li').fadeIn(1000); // tweek for IE

    $('div.rotator ul li').hover(function() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    },
    function() {
        interval = setInterval(rotate, 5000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to retrieve the interval handle that is returned by the `setInterval` function. Also, I used `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` as they are better suited for the functionality you want.

```
function theRotator() {
    //Set the opacity of all images to 0
    $('div.rotator ul li').css({opacity: 0.0});

    //Get the first image and display it (gets set to full opacity)
    $('div.rotator ul li:first').css({opacity: 1.0});

    //Call the rotator function to run the slideshow,

    window.rotatorInterval = setInterval(rotate,5000);
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    //Load the slideshow
    theRotator();

    $('div img').mouseenter(function(){
         clearInterval(window.rotatorInterval);
    }).mouseleave(function() {
         window.rotatorInterval = setInterval(rotate, 5000);
    });

    $('div.rotator').fadeIn(1000);
    $('div.rotator ul li').fadeIn(1000); // tweek for IE
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
var rotate = true;

$('img').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        rotate = false;
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        rotate = true;
    }
});​
```

and check that flag in your `rotate()` function